# delete records which entered 15 minutes ago in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting time and date using `now()` in `mysql`. the datatype of column is `varchar`.
How to deleted older records which entered 15 minutes ago.

Comment: DONOT Store dates as varchar

Comment: Wow, it must be early. Sorry.

Answer (score 7):

You should probably store as datetime; and by probably, I mean you must. Use this though:

```
delete from table where date < date_sub(now(), interval 15 minute);
```